# Unable to locate element using Selenium Python find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I have input:

```
<input type="text" class="cell-danhgia" kpi-chitieu="001" id="txt-danhgia-001" value="0">
```

I use Selenium with python to select input. My code is:

```
button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='txt-danhgia-001']")
u = '100'
button.send_keys(u)
```

But I can not locate input. I've got an error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='txt-danhgia-001']"}
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)
```

Please help to how to select this input. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check if element is inside any frame? and provided some delay as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Nguyen, Since I do not know the url but may be the element is taking time to load. So it is good to wait for its visibility.

Try this:

```
button  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txt-danhgia-001']")))
```

instead of :

```
button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='txt-danhgia-001']")
```

in your code.

You will need the following import for it to work:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

If this does not work then other possibilities may be element is inside an iframe/frame. In that case, you need to first switch to the frame using `driver.switch_to.frame(frametoswitchto)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'txt-danhgia-001')
```

You could also shorten your code to:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'txt-danhgia-001').send_keys('100')
```